# SQL Select statement until a character

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking to extract all the text up until a `'\'` (backslash).

The substring is required to remove all proceeding characters (17 in total) and so I would like to return all after the 17th until it comes across a backslash.

I've tried using charindex but it doesn't seem to stop at the `\` it returns characters afterward. My code is as follows

```
SELECT path, substring(path,17, CHARINDEX('\',Path)+ LEN(Path)) As Data
  FROM [Table].[dbo].[Projects]
  WHERE Path like '\ENQ%\' AND 
  Deleted = '0'
```

Example

The below screen shot shows the basic query and result i.e the whole string
[image: Image 1]

I then use substring to remove the first X characters as there will always be the same amount of proceeding characters

[image]

But what Im actually after is (based on the above result) the "Testing 1" "Testing 2" and "Testing ABC" section

Comment: Show us some input data for all cases, and expected output for each case.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand - Im not inputting into the table. Do you mean use insert which inserts sample data and then query that data?

Answer (score 1):

> The substring is required to remove all proceeding characters (17 in total) and so I would like to return all after the 17th until it comes across a backslash.

```
select 
substring(path,17,CHARINDEX('\',Path)-17)
from
table
```

To overcome `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function` error, you can use CASE

```
 select 
    substring(path,17,
   CASE when  CHARINDEX('\',Path,17)>0
        Then  CHARINDEX('\',Path)-17)
        else VA end
           )
    from
    table
```

Comment: Thanks if I use your example I get Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: it may be  due to length  field getting negative values.there might be some fields,which may not have `\`,so when we subtract 17,the value becomes negative.can you add sample data